# Creating a hash that doesn't include its salt in PHP

Tags: php, encryption, hash

For user verification emails, I want to send my users an email that includes a secure hash based on the user id and a randomly generated salt. However all of php's functions are aimed towards password hashing, and so store the salt in the hash for password verification. Since I intent to send the user this hash, there is no need for this.

I'm aware of the md5 function, which doesn't include the salt, but I'm lead to believe an md5 hash is not secure.

Is there any way to hash (preferably with one line of code) a string in php and return a pure hash without the salt?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add a salt to any hash. It is just a string added to whatever you are hashing. However, the best method to use here is a random string that you store along with the email address on your server. When the user attempts to verify, you compare to the random string. Then, there is no need to worry about someone producing a hash based solely on knowledge of the email address.

Answer (score 1):

I don't completely get your protocol, but if you are just looking for a secure hash in PHP, then use [hash](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.hash.php) with `algo = "sha256"`.

Make sure you understand which (default) character encoding is used when you hash a string with PHP.

Answer (score 0):

hash using base64_encode first and then the resulted value should hashed again with md5. that will return you with secure hashing result.

Answer (score 0):

As far as i understood, this is not a salt at all, instead you want to use a *key* with which you can hide the userid. The userid is what you want to verify later on. To be able to verify this userid, you have to store the key somewhere.

Now if you have to store this key anyway, then you could take a better apporach. Generate a *random* token which is not derrived from any existing data (and cannot leak anything), and store a hash of this token together with the userid in the database. The original token you send to the user. As soon as the user clicks the link you can verify the token with the stored hash.

Because the random token is a very strong "password" (about 20 randomly choosen characters) it is absolutely safe to calculate a simple hash like SHA-256 without a salt. This allows to search for the hashed token in the database.